# php issue with including file

Tags: php, oop

I have 2 files. The first one contains (db.php)

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '123456';
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=myclass",$dbuser,$dbpass);
```

The second one contains (users.php)

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

class Users {

public function register() {

    $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Users(user, pass) VALUES (?,?)');
    $query->bindValue(1,'user');
    $query->bindValue(2,'pass');
    $query->execute();

}
}

$myUser = new Users();

$myUser->register();

?>
```

When I try to load the second file , the data does not show.
And when I try to write "$db->" then nothing appears that I can add in there from the drop down. 
Do you have an idea why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: Basic PHP: Variable scope is at the function/object level. Within register(), $db is not defined. You need `global $db` at bare minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject `$db` into your class.  You can use the constructor:

```
class Users {

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function register() {
        $query = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO Users(user, pass) VALUES (?,?)');
        // etc...
    }
}
```

---

```
include('db.php');
include('users.php');

$myUser = new Users($db);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is those variables in the `db.php` is not accessible inside your class !

Better initialize all those values in the `db.php` inside your class through a `constructor`

You gotta do something like this..

```
class Users {

    private $dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$db;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->dbhost = 'localhost';
        $this->dbuser = 'root';
        $this->dbpass = '123456';
        $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->dbhost;dbname=myclass",$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass);

    }

    public function register() {

        $query = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO Users(user, pass) VALUES (?,?)');
        $query->bindValue(1,'user');
        $query->bindValue(2,'pass');
        $query->execute();

    }
}

$myUser = new Users();
$myUser->register();
```

Comment: Why would you maintain credentials and object instantiation in every class that uses the DB?  What happens if you change to postgres or another driver or change passwords, etc...?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `<?php` and `?>` in db.php. Possibly the code is not being interpreted as PHP.